# Best reply for is was a pleasure meeting you

Tags: word-choice

if some one send to me: it was a real pleasure meeting you, what is the best to reply with?
The pleasure was really mine/us or it was a pleasure too?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. There's a whole range of possible answers, ranging from "Thank you" to "The pleasure was mine", with some neutral and perhaps even derogatory replies possible (try to avoid the derogatory ones :) ). Which is *best* depends on the context, including your intent. If you provide more context, the EL&U community would be better placed to give you an appropriate answer. As it stands, there are several votes to close since EL&U is geared towards questions that can be answered definitively. Have a look at [this introductory page](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Another Stack Exchange site that might be better for questions like this one is [ell.se].

Answer (score 1):

It is common to respond simply with **"Likewise"**.  Here is a link to a definition that fits your case perfectly.

> [likewise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likewise): similarly so with me [answered “likewise” to “Pleased to meet you”]

Answer (score 0):

> It was a pleasure to meet you

The best reply?

*The pleasure was all yours.*

It's not nice, it's not appropriate, but in my humble opinion, it is the best.

Comment: dude, the Trump troll was funny.  This is just mean.

Comment: This seems like the tongue-in-cheek dark, twisted brit humour...